# KeyError at /admin/login/ 'request'

Tags: django

What could be the cause of this issue? I have looked at similar questions and most of the answers recommended are things I have already configured in my settings file.

When I try login to the admin section.
This error shows up

```
KeyError at /admin/login/
'request'
```

the request context processor [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) is already part of the configuration

here is my TEMPLATE configuration

```
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
           'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

AUTH BACKENDS

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

]
```

Django 1.11

PS: I am using djangorestframework as well, any ideas if it's somehow affecting this?

Full Traceback

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  72.             inspect.getcallargs(backend.authenticate, request, **credentials)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/inspect.py" in getcallargs
  1344.                             (f_name, kw))

During handling of the above exception (authenticate() got multiple values for argument 'request'), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in inner
  52.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in login
  393.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in dispatch
  90.         return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  182.         if form.is_valid():

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  175.             self.full_clean()

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  385.         self._clean_form()

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  412.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean
  187.             self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)

File "/Users/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  77.                 inspect.getcallargs(backend.authenticate, request=request, **credentials)

Exception Type: KeyError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: 'request'
```

Comment: Can you share the *full* traceback?

Comment: updated question with traceback, seems like an anonymous user issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be a django 1.11 specific bug.
It was fixed in django 1.11.4

I found the answer here [django admin request login bug](https://github.com/imanhodjaev/django-auth0/issues/15)